# Facebook bot suddenly giving GatewayTimeout error

Tags: botframework

I have a facebook bot that has a very high traffic and suddenly it started to give the error

```
There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code GatewayTimeout

 Activity reply = activity.CreateReply(translation);

                                await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
                                var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                                return response;
```

this is the reply code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there was a degradation of the Bot Facebook service yesterday between 2pm and 5pm PST and possibly you were affected by that.

Related threads: [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2142) and [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2140).